# Adding a prefix to start of string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string being passed to me which can be between 1 and 6 characters long. Depending on the length of the string I need to add the appropriate prefix to the start of the string and return the appeneded string. So if I have something like the following passed to me

- 1
- 12
- 123
- 1234
- 12345
- 123456

I want the return string to look like

- X000001
- X000012
- X000123
- X001234
- X012345
- X123456

I have come up with the following method

```
public static string AddToStartOfString(string s)
{
    string value = string.Empty;

    switch (s.Length)
    {
      case 1:
         value = "X00000" + s;
         break;
      case 2:
         value = "X0000" + s;
         break;
      case 3:
         value = "X000" + s;
         break;
      case 4:
         value = "X00" + s;
         break;
      case 5:
         value = "X0" + s;
         break;
      case 6:
         value = "X" + s;
         break;
    }
    return value;
}
```

This works. But I need this to work in case in future more lengths are added. Is there a way where I can add the prefix even if the length of string is greater than 6 in the future

Comment: Well what prefix would you want to add if the input is already (say) 10 characters?

Comment: @JonSkeet as per question: *"string being passed to me which can be between 1 and 6 characters long"*

Comment: @JonSkeet for now it's between 1 and 6 but from the future requirement the longest the string should get is 9

Comment: @AndyKorneyev: Yes, but "Is there a way where I can add the prefix even if the length of string is greater than 6 in the future". The point of the question is when the part you quoted *isn't* true.

Comment: @Code: Okay then, what prefix would you want to add if the input is already 9 characters? Basically, you haven't asked a well-specified question.

Comment: If all you want to do is add the prefix when the input string is greater than 6, then all you need to do with your method is change the final _case 6:_ to _default:_ - though do check the other answers for improved solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public static string AddToStartOfString(string s, int digitCount = 6)
{
    return "X" + s.PadLeft(digitCount, '0');
}
```

Beware that an input string longer than the max number of digits, once transformed, will not be truncated and will be longer than for values in the correct range.

Answer (score -1):

had a similar problem recently, in your case i would do:

```
public static string Fill(string str, string prefix, int length)
{
    for(int i=str.Length; i<length; i++)
        str = "0" + str;

    return prefix + str;
}
```

Comment: That's a horribly inefficient way of reimplementing `string.PadLeft`.